# como abrir archivos excel con un combo box? c#

Tags: c#, excel, combobox

buenas ando con la idea de un combobox que tenga cargado o al que se le pueda cargar archivos excel, y que rellenen con el nombre de excel, para poder abrirlos con un boton

el codigo :

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // FileStream stream = File.Open("myfile.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:/Users/Nero/Desktop/test");

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (string file in files)
                comboBox1.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
        }
```

mis preguntas serian si existe una forma de cargar los excel en el combobox para poder abrilos con buton?

Comment: Hola Nero. Si no entiendo mal, en el combo se cargarán los nombres de los Excel que tengas en un directorio. Acto seguido, cuando toques un botón, se abrirá el Excel que has seleccionado en el combo, ¿Correcto? Si es así, con ese código en el combo se te cargan los nombres, ¿Cierto?

Comment: apenas e pensado trate de usar el codigo pero no me funciono, pero si la idea es abrir los excel de un directorio para que queden guardados ahi y para que posteriormente se puedan abrir, algo como digamos que tengo 4 excel en el directorio, señalo uno con el combox, y lo abro posteriormente con un boton es decir queda cargado para realizar busqueda de parametros en este, creo que mi error esta en el path de getfile pero no se cual es

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que tienes un error de concepto del "cuando". Ahora está diciendo que se carguen los archivos cuando cambie el valor (índice) del combo (`SelectedIndexChanged`). Si el combo no se ha llenado previamente, eso no ocurrirá jamás.

En cualquier acción o lugar donde quieras que se carguen (por ejemplo en la carga del formulario) pones el código:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\Nero\Desktop\test");
foreach (string file in files)
    comboBox1.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
```

Ahora ya tendrás los nombres de los archivos cargados, luego, manteniendo el método que tenías, pones el código de lo que quieras hacer con el Excel seleccionado.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: no me funciono lamentablemente, la parte de foreach para abajo, me sale error si es que esta no esta dentro del combobox tambien me di cuenta que el path me marcaba error por / , modique el codigo pero sigue sin funcionar